how to fill msg data more easily in ros2 rclcpp?
i have following msg prototype:
# XY.msg
float32 x
float32 y

# Line.msg
XY[] points

in ros2 rclcpp, i need to fill data like:
std::vector<FOO> pts = GetData(); // assume FOO contains what needs
pkg::msg::Line line{};
for (auto pt : pts) {
  pkg::msg::XY xy{}
  xy.x = pt.x;
  xy.y = pt.y;
  line.push_back(xy);
}

the above takes too much code, i tried familiar cpp construction method as follow:
std::vector<FOO> pts = GetData(); // assume FOO contains what needs
pkg::msg::Line line{};
for (auto pt : pts) {
   line.push_back({pt.x, pt.y}); 
}

or
std::vector<FOO> pts = GetData(); // assume FOO contains what needs
pkg::msg::Line line{};
for (auto pt : pts) {
   pkg::msg::XY xy{pt.x,pt.y}
   line.push_back(xy); 
}

but all errors like
ros2 msg no matching function for call to std::vector... std::allocator... void push_back brace-enclosed initializer list...

is there a more easy way to fill data for this kind of nested/structed msg? thanks very much.

found it here:
Is there a concise way to initialize a message with specific values?
so my code should be
// #include pkg/msg/line.hpp
// #include pkg/msg/xy.hpp // is important

std::vector<FOO> pts = GetData(); // assume FOO contains what needs
pkg::msg::Line line{};
for (auto pt : pts) {
   line.push_back(pkg::build<pkg::msg::XY>().x(pt.x).y(pt.y));
}


